# Best practices and tools to perform code move for ASP.NET projects

Tags: asp.net, svn, version-control

I have a ASP.NET project with my own Development, Staging and Production servers.

In all environements, I move code manually. So everytime I have to promote a change, I perform the following steps:

1. Get my latest code from SVN.
2. Merge the code between lower and to be promoted environment using tools like Beyond Compare.
3. Then I move the respective ASPX and DLL files and any Stored Procedures or table data manually to Production.

This is a very time consuming process and I would like to get some automated methods for code moves.

Is there a way I can get the code moved from SVN to my Servers using some automated tools or in a automated packages.

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 with IIS 7 and SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. msbuild can help you with getting the code from svn and building it. You will need to create simple batch files to run it, alternatively you can use Cruisecontrol for that.
2. Manual merges should be avoided. If you are using VS2010, you can use xsd to transform your config files to production version
3. I am not a big fan of storedprocs. If you can encapsulate your stored procs with the code there is less room for errors and rolling back changes etc as well as making the deployment easier. Database schema updates should be done in a batch file and applied automatically.
4. There are multiple ways to deploy: webdeploy or msi file. It depends on how much work is required during the deployment process

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).  My favorite because it is simplest to use is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

You will still have to do some work with MSBuild.

You can set up the builds to be a button push from the site.
Have the code pushed when you check into svn.
Just about any way you can think of.

I would strongly urge you to use it to ALWAYS build you code and run unit tests on each SVN check it.  It does not have to deploy but TeamCity will provide to you constant feedback on the state of your solution.